# Marks.position variables

Tags: teechart, delphi-5

I cannot access the variables like 'lefttop' etc.

I know I have to set the custom property to true. The only way I can do this is by using a seperate declared TSeriesMarkPosition variable. But this overides all values.

If I do try to read the marks positions like 'cpos:=pieform.series1.Marks.positions[0];' beforehand

cpos obtains a nill property and becomes unusable.

BUT I can do this: cpos:=pieform.series1.Marks.positions[0], but then the assigned values are being overidden;

The objetive is to manupilate the Marks positions.

Can there be a problem with my Teechart, since I have been using this Delphi version for ages.

Search the inet.
Created the Pie charts in runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was, that during the cycle, assigning values to the pie chart, I also wanted to change the properties of MARKS.

I had to wait until this cycle was finished, the PIE displayed and then after I could change the custom property.

It does lead to some flickering if you change the values fast through the same pie.